# Find two paths in a Graph which are disjunct in

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, directed-graphs

Assuming we have two trains that start in one source edge. I want to find an algorithm that finds two paths for these trains so that they won't meet in an edge at any given time. So we have the train ride T=$ \left(\left(v_{i-1}, v_{i}, t_{i}\right)\right)_{i=1}^{k}$, starting in v_0 to v_k and t_k as the arrival time. In this case, the source does not count as a stay.

Input is as follows: The source edge and two destination edges, each for one train plus a set of additional vertices and edges which represent the connections and stops.
To make the statement "won't meet in an edge at any given time" more clear: each edge has their own finite amount of departure times. Meaning that a train can wait in one edge, but only for so long the edge has a departure left and can only leave when with the given departure times.

We have to find an algorithm that finds two paths in polynomial time.

My attempts so far:

- check for two disjunct paths via Ford/Fulkerson, but this does only work for single destinations, I guess

1. create a 2-d array A[i][j] where i and j are the edges of the graph.
2. Find a (shortest) path for the first Train T1
3. update A[i][j] with the time at which P1 arrives at that location
4. For T2 find a path
5. If T2 is about to travel to an edge, check whether P1 will be there
   by calculating the expected arrival time of T2 and compare this value A[i][j]
6. If yes, check the next edge and find a path to your destination
7. If no edge is available return "false" as there is no path in which
   P1 and P2 won't be at one location at the same time
8. If the path has been found, return true

My problem with this approach is the complexity as it'd rise if P2 had to constantly find new paths in case P2 runs into edges at which it would meet P1.

I'd be really thankful for a different approach or a little push in the right direction. I'm sorry about the terrible formatting, but I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your inputs? You get a graph, a source and an end node? Or do the trains need to visit multiple stops? Can the trains be at the same node?

Comment: @plshelp i edited my question/input. I hope this clears things up. :)